# How to vertically align a div in an h2 tag?

Tags: html, css

Well i want to vertically align three divs, one on the left and one on the right and another one in the middle.

Here is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MK01/6qxm3n5s/

Here is the html code:

```
<h2>
    <div></div>
    <div id="Title">My Title</div>
    <div></div>
</h2>
```

And here is the css code:

```
h2 div{
    float: left;
    width: 30%
}
h2 div:nth-child(1), h2 div:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #000;
    height: 1px
}
#Title{
    text-align: center
}
```

I have tried a lot of tricks and techniques but none seem to work.

Thank you, MMK.

Comment: The JavaScript tag is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using two extra elements for those lines, you could use :pseudo-elements.

```css
#Title:after,
#Title:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #000;
  height: 1px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 33.3%;
}
#Title:after {
  left: 66.66%;
}
#Title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 33.3%, tan 33.3%, tan 66.6%, transparent 66.6%);
}
```

```html
<h2><div id="Title">My Title</div></h2>
```

---

You could set the `width` of :pseudo-elements to `10%`(will add up to `20%`) if you want the title to be `80%`.

```css
#Title:after,
#Title:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #000;
  height: 1px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 10%;
}
#Title:after {
  left: 90%;
}
#Title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 10%, tan 10%, tan 90%, transparent 90%);
}
```

```html
<h2><div id="Title">My Title</div></h2>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how i could keep the #Title Width flexible for up to 80% and then based on that determine the width of the after and before :pseudo-elements. Or should i use three divs and javascript.

Comment: @MuhamadMuzahirKhodabucus  -No need for JavaScript here, I'll add an example for that as well.

Comment: @MuhamadMuzahirKhodabucus - I've added another snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use floats :(
You can do one of the following:
- apply `display: table` to parent and `display: table-cell` to child elements
- apply `display:inline` for inside-h2 divs

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to give your two outer divs a margin-top:

`h2 div:nth-child(1), h2 div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 13px;
}`

and your h2 tag a margin of 0 so it doesn't offset the three divs.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cmbufLpL/)**